# Sending form data from Spartacus Storefront to Hybris backend controller

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

How we can send form data from Spartacus storefront to the OCC backend (hybris' database)? what is the procedure?

Answer (score 2):

The standard functionality of Spartacus uses OCC API to communicate with Commerce Cloud backend using concept like Connector, Adapter and Convertor etc. You can follow Spartacus standard implementation's approach as well, details could be found from this document:

https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems

Best regards,
Jerry

Comment: Hi Jerry.. Thanks for replying. can I have a sample configuration set up of occ, adapter, facade, and converters to connect the backend system of hybris?